# How to send sms to a number using API when data is successfully inserted and also redirect it to my website pages

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

```
 $qins="INSERT INTO citizen_request(name,mobile,description,id,status,file) VALUES('$name','$mobile','$description','$id','$status','$new_image_name')";
    mysqli_query($con,$qins);
      if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0)
        {
 move_uploaded_file($image_temp,"upload/request/".$new_image_name);
 copy( __DIR__ . "/upload/request/".$new_image_name, __DIR__ . "/user/upload/request/".$new_image_name );

  $ch = curl_init('http://some.com/api/mt/SendSMS?urldata');
                    $response = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    echo $response;            
                    ?>

    <?php
                }
```

What m trying to do is send sms on successfull entry and redirect it to my page request-entry.php?success=yess , when using curl its returning "Bad Request

HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed." 
when m using redirection

```
<script language='javascript'>
location.href="http://some.com/api/mt/SendSMS?urldata";   
</script>
```

message is working successfully but it is going to the sms providers page.
And when using both the links like this

```
<script language='javascript'>
location.href="http://some.com/api/mt/SendSMS?urldata1";
location.href="request-entry.php?success=yess";    
</script>
```

it is redirecting to request-entry.php page but sms is not going

Comment: You can not make the client request _two_ resources at once, by assigning them both as _the_ (singular) new location.

Comment: Try and apply proper URL encoding to the parameters you insert into the URL with your cURL request. Browsers apply missing encoding on their own, but such request libraries usually don’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$message = rawurlencode('This is your message');
// Prepare data for POST request
$data = "futherurldata";
// Send the GET request with cURL
 $ch = curl_init('http://login.xyz.com/api/mt/SendSMS?' . $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// Process your response here
echo $response;
```

This should work